# React native and typescript multi inline styling

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, styles, stylesheet

I am trying to acieve some like this in react-native and typescript -

**`<View style={[styles.a, styles.b]}> </View>`**

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    a: {color: 'red'},
    b:{flex: 1}
})
```

But I am getting the following build error in typescript-

error TS2322: Type '{ style: (ViewStyle | ImageStyle)[]; children: Element[]; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes> & Reado...'.
  Type '{ style: (ViewStyle | ImageStyle)[]; children: Element[]; }' is not assignable to type 'Readonly'.
    Types of property 'style' are incompatible.
      Type '(ViewStyle | ImageStyle)[]' is not assignable to type 'ViewStyle | undefined'.
        Type '(ViewStyle | ImageStyle)[]' has no properties in common with type 'ViewStyle'.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

This is a workaround

`<View style={[styles.a, styles.b] as ViewStyle}> </View>`

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/17622#issuecomment-312050586

Answer (score 1):

Using the spread operator is probably the nicest way of doing this. This should return a single ViewStyle object

```js
<View style={{...styles.a, ...styles.b}}> </View>
```